# Getting data from foursquare API in php website

Tags: javascript, php, foursquare

I want to connect to Foursquare API and access places information from foursquare DB. I have tried a code which I found in stackoverflow.com for the same usage .Code is fine and I'm able to connect to API but not getting the access_token from foursquare.

These are the codes I've used.

**localhost/scripts/secrets.php**

```
<?php  
// insert your foursquare API keys
   define('CLIENT_ID', 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID');
   define('CLIENT_SECRET', 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');
```

**localhost/scripts/4sq_Login.php**

```
 <?php
  // Foursquare login stage 1, build url and redirect
    require_once('secrets.php'); //defines CLIENT_ID

 // build $url
    $url = 'https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate';
    $url .= '?client_id='.CLIENT_ID;
    $url .= '&response_type=code';
    $url .= '&redirect_uri=http://localhost/scripts/4sq_Callback.php'; // change to your 4sq callback
  // redirect
     header( 'Location: '.$url ) ;
```

**localhost/scripts/4sq_Callback.php**

```
     <?php
// Foursquare login step 2, echo back $code from QUERY_STRING
  require_once('secrets.php'); // defines CLIENT_ID & CLIENT_SECRET

// get $code from QUERY_STRING
  parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query);
  $code = $query['code'];

// build url
  $url = 'https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token';
  $url .= '?client_id='.CLIENT_ID;
  $url .= '&client_secret='.CLIENT_SECRET;
  $url .= '&grant_type=authorization_code';
  $url .= '&redirect_uri=http://localhost/scripts/4sq_Callback.php'; //change to your 4sq callback
  $url .= '&code='.$code;

// call to https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token with $code
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

// $result value is json {access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN}
  $values = json_decode($result, true);
  $token = $values['access_token'];

// set access_token cookie (if you wish)
  $expire = time()+2592000; // 30 days from now
  setcookie("foursquare_token", $token, $expire, '/');

// crosswindow scripting to pass back $token
  echo('<script type="text/javascript">');
  echo('opener.set4sqKey("'.$token.'");');
  echo('self.close();'); // close self
  echo('</script>');
```

**localhost/index.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>FourSquare test page...</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var foursquareKey;

// Open foursquare login window.
function get4sqKey(){
  if(!foursquareKey){
    window.open('scripts/4sq_Login.php', 'foursquareAuth', 'width=960, height=548');
  }
}

// called crosswindow by login window
function set4sqKey(key){
  foursquareKey = key;
  setTimeout('alert("Logged into Foursquare");', 1); // setTimeout makes alert non-blocking
}

// simple alert to display OAuth token
function showKey(){
  alert(foursquareKey);
}

// -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:get4sqKey();">get4sqKey();</a> |
<a href="javascript:showKey();">showKey();</a>
</body>
</html>
```

With this code I'm able to connect Foursquare API but when tried the java script function **showKey();**, no access_token is getting printed.

Comment: You did provide valid CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET values?

Comment: Yes ,I have provided everything correctly.

Comment: Did you hardcode the link in the url? See if you get the correct response in the browser.

Comment: no i am getting only the page code (index.htm) as a response @BrettSantore